# Not getting children of object with filter

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using a filter on an array with objects that have children. But when i filter on the parent i only get the data i filtered on and not the children of that parent. What am I doing wrong ?

```
app.get('/api/categories/:category', (req, res) => {
    res.send(getFilteredCategories(req.params.category));
  });


function getFilteredCategories(category){
    const categorieArray = [categories];
    const filteredCategory = categorieArray.filter(d => d.productCategoryLevel1Description = category);
    console.log(filteredCategory);
    return filteredCategory;   
}
```

for example when i go "http://localhost:3000/api/categories/Cartons" I'm getting

```
[
{
"productCategoryLevel1Description": "Cartons"
}
]
```

but what i want is :

```
"productCategoryLevel1": "1",
"productCategoryLevel1Description": "Cartons",
"sortingKeyLevel1": 1,
"children": [
{
"productCategoryLevel2": "1.1",
"productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 1.1",
"productCategoryLevel1": "1",
"children": [
{
"productCategoryLevel3": "1.1.1",
"productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.1.1",
"productCategoryLevel2": "1.1",
"categoryCount": 3
},
{
"productCategoryLevel3": "1.1.2",
"productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.1.2",
"productCategoryLevel2": "1.1",
"categoryCount": 1
},
{
"productCategoryLevel3": "1.1.3",
"productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.1.3",
"productCategoryLevel2": "1.1",
"categoryCount": 2
},
{
"productCategoryLevel3": "1.1.4",
"productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.1.4",
"productCategoryLevel2": "1.1",
"categoryCount": 2
}
]
},
```

Categories is a json object i'm getting from a fetch. This is whats inside categories

```
 [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel1": "1",
    "productCategoryLevel1Description": "Cartons",
    "sortingKeyLevel1": 1,
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 1.1",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "1",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.1.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.1.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.1",
    "categoryCount": 3
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.1.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.1.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.1",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.1.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.1.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.1",
    "categoryCount": 2
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.1.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.1.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.1",
    "categoryCount": 2
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 1.2",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "1",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.2.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.2.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.2",
    "categoryCount": 2
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.2.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.2.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.2",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.2.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.2.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.2",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.2.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.2.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.2",
    "categoryCount": 3
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 1.3",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "1",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.3.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.3.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.3",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.3.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.3.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.3",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.3.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.3.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.3",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.3.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.3.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.3",
    "categoryCount": 0
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 1.4",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "1",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.4.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.4.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.4",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.4.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.4.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.4",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.4.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.4.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.4",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.4.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.4.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.4",
    "categoryCount": 0
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.5",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 1.5",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "1",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.5.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.5.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.5",
    "categoryCount": 4
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.5.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.5.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.5",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.5.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.5.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.5",
    "categoryCount": 3
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.5.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.5.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.5",
    "categoryCount": 0
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.6",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 1.6",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "1",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.6.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.6.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.6",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.6.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.6.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.6",
    "categoryCount": 2
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.6.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.6.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.6",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.6.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.6.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.6",
    "categoryCount": 4
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.7",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 1.7",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "1",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.7.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.7.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.7",
    "categoryCount": 3
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.7.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.7.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.7",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.7.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.7.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.7",
    "categoryCount": 2
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.7.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.7.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.7",
    "categoryCount": 2
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.8",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 1.8",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "1",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.8.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.8.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.8",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.8.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.8.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.8",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.8.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.8.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.8",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.8.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.8.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.8",
    "categoryCount": 2
    }
    ]
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel1": "2",
    "productCategoryLevel1Description": "Films",
    "sortingKeyLevel1": 2,
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 2.1",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "2",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.1.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.1.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.1",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.1.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.1.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.1",
    "categoryCount": 5
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.1.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.1.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.1",
    "categoryCount": 2
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.1.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.1.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.1",
    "categoryCount": 0
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 2.2",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "2",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.2.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.2.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.2",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.2.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.2.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.2",
    "categoryCount": 3
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.2.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.2.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.2",
    "categoryCount": 2
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.2.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.2.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.2",
    "categoryCount": 2
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 2.3",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "2",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.3.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.3.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.3",
    "categoryCount": 4
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.3.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.3.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.3",
    "categoryCount": 2
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.3.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.3.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.3",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.3.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.3.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.3",
    "categoryCount": 2
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 2.4",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "2",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.4.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.4.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.4",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.4.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.4.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.4",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.4.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.4.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.4",
    "categoryCount": 2
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.4.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.4.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.4",
    "categoryCount": 1
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.5",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 2.5",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "2",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.5.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.5.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.5",
    "categoryCount": 4
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.5.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.5.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.5",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.5.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.5.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.5",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.5.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.5.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.5",
    "categoryCount": 0
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.6",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 2.6",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "2",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.6.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.6.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.6",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.6.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.6.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.6",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.6.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.6.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.6",
    "categoryCount": 3
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.6.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.6.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.6",
    "categoryCount": 2
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.7",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 2.7",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "2",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.7.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.7.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.7",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.7.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.7.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.7",
    "categoryCount": 2
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.7.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.7.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.7",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.7.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.7.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.7",
    "categoryCount": 3
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.8",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 2.8",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "2",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.8.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.8.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.8",
    "categoryCount": 3
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.8.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.8.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.8",
    "categoryCount": 2
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.8.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.8.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.8",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.8.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.8.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.8",
    "categoryCount": 3
    }
    ]
    }
    ]
    },
    {},
    {}
    ]
```

so what I wanna do is filter on cartons for example and get all cartons with the children of carton.

Comment: I don't think there's nearly enough information in your post for anybody to diagnose your problem

Comment: First off, I see that the condition in your filter statement only has 1 `=` it should be `===`

Comment: I have edited my topic, could you have a look. I'm still trying to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be: `const filteredCategory = categorieArray.filter(d => d.productCategoryLevel1Description = category);`

You need to use == or === to check for equality (prefer === to check type as well as value)

also `const categorieArray = [categories];`

you are creating an array of a single  entry - the categories object. If Categories is already an array you can do `categories.filter`. If categories not an array you need to do some work on before you can use `.filter` as it exists only on Array types, e.g. `Object.values(catgories).filter()`

Comment: I have edited my topic, could you have a look. I'm still trying to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFilteredCategories(category){
    //check next line
    const categorieArray = Json;
    const filteredCategory = categorieArray.filter(d => d.productCategoryLevel1Description == category);
    console.log(filteredCategory);
    return filteredCategory;   
}
```

This will work!
The problem with your code is that you are copying the array , which shallow copies the array , before it is going to filter, the array is being stripped(nested elements aren't being copied), when you use filter it gives you new array so you don't need to run filter on copied array as it doesn't mutates the original array.

just  run filter on original array and it will work fine